# Do I need a Phpmyadmin account while uploading my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've done my first website using phpmyadmin + local wordpress and now I'm ready to upload it on my Host service.

Do I need to make an account for my Phpmyadmin for security reason (and maybe upload it to the server? Or is it just secure with the wp account?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are using cPanel you can use MYSQL Database Wizard to create a new database and user. After that head over to phpMyAdmin and import your WordPress database file into the database you just created. You will only need your cPanel credentials for all this.

Answer (score 0):

Every Host Service have certain security options. When you create any database in server you need to create a Username and Password before it. You just use the same in your wp-config.php to get that connection to your wordpress in your host.